# Wrong output for slice matrix

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to write a very simple code for n*n matrices to produce slice matrix. However, I get the wrong slice matrix when run using Geany and Gfortran.

The code is:

```
program mat_slice

implicit none
integer, parameter:: n = 3
integer, dimension(n,n) :: mat
integer, dimension(n-1,n-1) :: slice
logical, dimension(n,n) :: mask
integer :: i,j
mat = reshape((/1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9/),(/n,n/))

print*, mat

mask = .true.
mask(i,:) = .false.
mask(:,j) = .false.

slice = reshape((pack(mat,mask)),(/n-1,n-1/))

do i  =  1,n-1
    do  j = 1,n-1
        print*, slice(i,j)
    end do
end do
```

end program mat_slice

The output is
**0
4
0
5**

However, when I run the same code on Jdoodle, I get the correct answer that's.

The output is

**1
4
2
5**

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your values `i` and `j` are undefined at their first use

```
mask(i,:) = .false. 
mask(:,j) = .false.
```

and your program is therefore invalid.

Probably values 0 are used abd the program accesses the arrays uout of bounds. Always first compile your programs with all debugging checks and warnings. In gfortran use `-g -fbacktrace -Wall -fcheck=all` for start. Consult the manual for more.